# Como poner multiple marker en c# usando GMAP

Tags: c#, google-maps

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
GMarkerGoogle marker;
GMapOverlay markerOverlay;
```

Simple configuracion inicial:

```
gMapControl1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
gMapControl1.CanDragMap = true;
gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(LatInicial,LngInicial);
gMapControl1.MinZoom = 0;
gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 24;
gMapControl1.Zoom = 9;
gMapControl1.AutoScroll = true;
```

Agregando el MARKER

```
//Marcador
markerOverlay = new GMapOverlay("Marcador");
marker = new GMarkerGoogle(newPointLatLng(25.00000,-25.00000),GMarkerGoogleType.green);
markerOverlay.Markers.Add(marker); //agregar marker al mapa
```

Alli solo me agrega 1 como puedo poner varios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `Markers` de `GMapOverLay` es una colección, de manera que puedes añadir nuevos markers tal como estás haciendo ahí, creando una nueva instancia de `GMarkerGoogle` y pasándola como argumento al método `Add()`. Algo así:

```
    // Declaras un nuevo marker
    GMarkerGoogle marker2 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(25.00000,-25.00000), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
    // Lo añades a la colección
    markerOverlay.Markers.Add(marker2);
```